# Configuring NGINX with WordPress Multisite installed in a sub-directory

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, server, multisite

I am attempting to install a WordPress Multisite on an NGINX server.  The multisite is a sub-domain install, and WordPress is installed in its own directory.  Most everything works (front end pages, categories, posts, admin functionality, etc.), but when trying to navigate to the Multisite Network admin (`/wp-admin/network`) I get a 404 error.  This works if I manually add my subdirectory to the url (`/wp/wp-admin/network`), but it won't automatically redirect.  I have tried many different configurations in my NGINX conf file, with no success.  Below is what I have landed on for the conf file as for now.

```
upstream php {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

map $http_host $blogid {
    default -999;

    #Ref: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-helper/
    include /var/www/vhosts/test.example.com/public/wp-content/uploads/nginx-helper/map.conf ;
}

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name test.example.com *.test.example.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    root /var/www/vhosts/test.example.com/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;         
                rewrite ^/wp(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /wp$2 last;      
                rewrite ^/wp(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php)$ /wp$2 last;
        }

    location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

    location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

    location /wp-admin {
        rewrite ^/wp-admin$ /wp/wp-admin/ redirect;
    }

    location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php?$args;
    }

    location /wp {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /wp/index.php;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wp)(/.*)$;
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }

    #WPMU Files
        location ~ ^/files/(.*)$ {
                try_files /wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/$blogid/$uri /wp/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 ;
                access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
        }

        #WPMU x-sendfile to avoid php readfile()
    location ^~ /blogs.dir {
            internal;
            alias /var/www/test.example.com/public/wp-content/blogs.dir;
            access_log off;     log_not_found off;      expires max;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have tried to follow the setup instructions on the NGINX site without success: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

I also read on the NGINX site that using ifs in the conf file is not a good idea, so I am not sure that the following block is very kosher.

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;         
    rewrite ^/wp(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /wp$2 last;      
    rewrite ^/wp(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php)$ /wp$2 last;
}
```

Any assistance to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even with mutli-site, don't you need a different virtual host for each one?

Comment: Also, this might help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-wordpress-multisite-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @Difster It is my understanding that a separate host file for each site is not necessary with the wildcard DNS entry and including the wildcard in the `server_name` directive.

As for the digital ocean article, it is great, but does not help me resolve the issue at hand with installing WP in a sub-directory.  With this setup, on a NGINX server, the rewrites for accessing the network administration area don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156420/125559, it sounds like this configuration will not work for a WordPress Multisite.